# Pandas numbers in index are strings/object

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

Running

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(df.iloc[index,0])
```

yields the following error:

> ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer
> slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of
> integers, boolean array] types

Index is `0`:

```
index
Out[57]: '0'
```

But somehow, my index consists of strings which I can confirm via

```
type(index)
Out[63]: str
```

This is although I've applied `df.reset_index()`.

How can I ensure that the index of my df (`df.index`) consists of integers?

**EDIT:**

```
df.index
Out[69]: 
Index(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
       ...
       '14829', '14830', '14831', '14832', '14833', '14834', '14835', '14836',
       '14837', '14838'],
      dtype='object', length=14839)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [85]: df.index
Out[85]: Index(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], dtype='object')

In [86]: df.index = df.index.astype(int)

In [87]: df.index
Out[87]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Make use of `astype`

Answer (score 0):

index results in '0' which means it is a string. You can easily make it an integer by using int() function.

At your case, `int(index)` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will not change the entire `df.index()` to ints.

Comment: I've updated my question to make my request more clear.

Comment: Well, you make try to use `df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype(int)` after creating the DataFrame.